# Load multiple csv files from a directory using dataloader

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

I have data in multiple CSV files(having same header name) in a directory. I want to create vertices from those CSV files. How can i load all files with a single load using dse graph loader. because i have almost more then 600 csv file ?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that graph loader the tool for the job.  The docs have a good example [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/dgl/dglCSV.html).

Comment: thanks . But this is not related to my question. i asked how to load multiple files?

Comment: I dont know if the mapping script can accept wildcards for the file names but if not the other option might be to concatenate all your csv files into one or even several larger files and load them? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes what @markc said is the only way I am aware of loading multiples at once.